# How to set maximum execution time for ajax post with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Is there a way to specify maximum execution time of an ajax post to the server so if the server doesn't respond, then keep trying for 10 seconds and then continue with the rest of the code??

```
Function doajaxPost(){
    var returned_value="";

    // #############I NEED THIS CODE TO TRY TO POST THE DATA TO THE SERVER AND KEEP
    // #############TRYING FOR 10 SECONDS AND THEN CONTINUE WITH THE REST OF THE CODE.
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
            success: function (result) {                               
                returned_value=result;
            },
            async: false
        });
    // ###################################################

    alert(returned_value);

    some other code
    .
    .
    .           
 }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `timeout`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
    success: function (result) {                               
        returned_value=result;
    },
    timeout: 10000,
    async: false
});
```

However, `alert(returned_value);` will execute just after your call (won't wait for the call to finish).

Comment: Be aware this won't retry. It will only try once.

Comment: you can't use timeout if your using async:false.

Answer (score 10):

The JQuery API documentation tells how to set a "timeout".

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

While other answers here are correct, learning to check the documentation for yourself is more valuable than knowing just this answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can set timeout value for your ajax request.

[timeout](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override
>   any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts
>   at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in
>   progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible
>   for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and
>   below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the
>   request times out; accessing any object members may throw an
>   exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be
>   cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after
>   the timeout period.

Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "ajaxhandler.php",
   ...
   timeout: 10000,
   ... 
});
```

Comment: how is this possible can you please demonstrate it?

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with `$.ajaxSetup()`. The timeout period starts at the point the `$.ajax` call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the `XMLHttpRequest` object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will help others like me who aren't completely fluent in JavaScript or, more to the point, aren't completely fluent in reading jQuery documentation.

I admit, I looked at the [jQuery.Ajax docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and easily enough found the section that talks about setting a timeout:

> **timeout**
> Type: Number
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. A value of 0 means there will be no timeout. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. **In jQuery 1.4.x and below**, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. **In Firefox 3.0+ only**, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

But lacking an example, I was still clueless ***how*** to specify the timeout value. The secret sauce is at the top of the article, where it says:

[image: screenshot of jQuery documentation page]

In JavaScript, this translates to this sort of syntax:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://example.com/my-endpoint",
   ...
   timeout: 0,
   ... 
});
```

In the above example (which specifies a `timeout` of 0 to disable timeouts for this request), each **key/value pair** (as mentioned in the documentation) appears in the code as `[key]: [value]`